# Make Linq to Sql generate T-SQL with ISNULL instead of COALESCE

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have a linq to sql query that returns some orders with non zero balance (in fact, the query is a little bit complicated, but for simplicity I omitted some details). This query also should return orders with no CardItems (both sub-queries return NULL in T-SQL, and comparing two NULLS gives FALSE, so I convert NULL result values of sub-queries to 0 for comparing).

```
var q = (from o in db.Orders
         where db.Cards(p =>
             p.OrderId == o.Id 
             && p.Sum + (db.CardItems.Where(i => i.IncomeId == p.Id)
                        .Sum(i => (double?)i.Amount) ?? 0) 
                    != (db.CardItems.Where(i => i.DeductId == p.Id)
                        .Sum(i => (double?)i.Amount) ?? 0)
            ).Any()
         select o);
```

**The problem is**, that converting expression Sum(i => (double?)i.Amount) ?? 0 **produce COALESCE** operator, which is ten times slower than exactly the same T-SQL query with replaced COALESCE to **ISNULL** because of sub-query in it. Is there any possibility to generate ISNULL in this situation?

Comment: As a technical question this has lots of merit. However as a programmer I have to ask - this kind of micro-optimisation seems wrong, does it matter?

Comment: @PreetSangha, what's "wrong" about writing a code the right way if you know where's the problem? I consider a wrong approach, when even though you know about the problem, you don't do anything about it... If you willingly produce a code that's 10-times slower than it could be, it's quite interesting to call the optimization "wrong"...

Comment: I think `?? 0` part is resulting for the coalesce

Comment: @V4Vendetta, yes, I know it, and I'm curious about possibility to generate ISNULL instead.

Comment: @Harm Not sure can you check if you can use `.GetValueOrDefault(0)` after you cast to `double?`

Comment: @V4Vendetta, same result. Actually, I believe that GetValueOrDefault(0) method has identical IL with null-coalescing operator.

Comment: @Harm : if Order HAS CardItems, do both subqueries have an non null sum of Amount, or not always ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, not always, because it's possible that Order has CardItems only with incomes or deducts or with both, so one SUM can be NULL.

Comment: @walther: Many others have said why premature optimizations are evil. OP: Is the overall run time of the query significantly affected? That should guide whether or not this should matter to you, not your previous experience with the operator.

Comment: What about trying "db.CardItems.Any(...) ? db.CardItems.Where(...).Sum(i => i.Amount) : 0"

Comment: @Guvante, and many others have said why willingly writing a bad code with words "I'll maybe fix it later" is a bad approach... If you know that your code is bad, don't wait till it becomes an issue... Just my opinion, maybe you like to fix things later :)

Comment: @walther: There is nothing to fix unless there is an actual performance problem. And I don't see any actual performance test to show that `COALESCE` is causing him issues, just him saying that he heard it was bad to do that. In either case he shouldn't be doing anything like that (as Oblivion2000's answer shows) so it is a moot point.

Comment: @Guvante, you both misunderstood the problem. Oblivion2000's answer is not right for my case. COALESCE **is** causing me issues, because it evaluates sub-query twice. You can read about it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/336002/unnecessarily-bad-performance-for-coalesce-subquery)

Comment: @Phil this will result in querying CardItems twice again in both sub-queries which I try to avoid.

Comment: Yes, but the 'where exists' sub-query generated for .Any should be fast.  Also I notice that using Linq to Entities does seem to use IS NULL.

Comment: @Harm: My point is you didn't provide enough information in the OP to prove that was the issue. Try rewording, or even better, including times that are inappropriate for your use case. OP just seems to say "I heard this was a problem so I want to remove it", not "I am getting performance below what is acceptable and I think maybe this is the problem".

Comment: What is not clear in the statement "is ten times slower than exactly the same T-SQL query with replaced COALESCE to ISNULL"? By this I mean, that I actually did tests with both variants of query. Also, why I should prove anything, when issue is well known?

Comment: Guys, the OP has clearly shown that ISNULL is preferable in his case. Either provide him a workaround or answer the question! No need to argue further.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap your data in a View, and have the View do the `ISNULL()` portion for you? I use this technique often at work, because we have a lot of legacy systems which have strangely implemented business rules - which we tighten through the use of views that default properties and so on.

Comment: @TroyAlford, I have legacy database to work with and unfortunately it is not desirable to make any changes to its schema.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044661/can-linq-to-sql-generate-tsql-containing-the-isnull-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, coaxing linq into generating the SQL you want is a hassle at best. If you've got an query implementation that's better than linq (works correctly and performs well), go ahead and use it, even if just for this one query.

The quickest way is probably with `DataContext.ExecuteQuery<TResult>`. It will even hydrate and handle the returned objects for you, just as if linq generated the query itself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx

Many people would rather put this SQL in a stored procedure, especially in production code. Then you just have to map the stored procedure into your linq objects, and it works the same way. As is often the case, ScottGu has a rather detailed post about how to do that:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are assuming a row without an Amount is to be summed as zero, then you can just filter out rows without the amount, and don't worry about the IsNull or coalesce.

```
&& p.Sum + (db.CardItems.Where(i => i.IncomeId == p.Id)
                    .Where(i=> i.Amount > 0)
                    .Sum(i => (double?)i.Amount) ?? 0) 
                != (db.CardItems.Where(i => i.DeductId == p.Id)
                    .Where(i=> i.Amount > 0)
                    .Sum(i => (double?)i.Amount) ?? 0)
```

Since I don't know your objects, you may even be able to remove the casts (double?) and default (??) operators

Comment: If remove null-coalescing ?? operator, your query will not return Orders with no CardItems (SUM operator will return NULL, comparison with NULL always returns FALSE), it will be equally with `&& p.Sum + (db.CardItems.Where(i => i.IncomeId == p.Id).Sum(i => i.Amount)) != (db.CardItems.Where(i => i.DeductId == p.Id).Sum(i => i.Amount)`. If leave ?? on it's place it will not give any advantage, because of generating almost the same T-SQL as origin. Problem is not in NULL Amount, this column is not even nullable, but in NULL SUM.