# Can LINQ to SQL generate TSQL containing the ISNULL function?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I was wondering whether anyone knows definitively if LINQ to SQL has the capability of generating TSQL code that contains the `ISNULL` function?

I'm aware that using the coalesce operator (`??`) in a query:

```cs
from o in Table
where (o.Field ?? 0) > 0
select o
```

will cause LINQ to SQL to emit the `COALESCE` function:

```sql
SELECT [t0].[Field]
FROM [Table] AS [t0]
WHERE (COALESCE([t0].[Field],0)) > 0
```

And, that using the conditional operator (`?:`) in a query:

```cs
from o in Table
where (o.Field == null ? 0 : o.Field) > 0
select o
```

will result in TSQL containing a `CASE` statement:

```sql
SELECT [t0].[Field]
FROM [Table] AS [t0]
WHERE (
    (CASE
        WHEN [t0].[Field] IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE [t0].[Amount]
     END)) > 0
```

But, can LINQ to SQL be coerced into generating TSQL code that contains `ISNULL` like the following?

```sql
SELECT [t0].[Field]
FROM [Table] AS [t0]
WHERE (ISNULL([t0].[Field],0)) > 0
```

I'm betting the answer is "no, it can't," but I'd like to see something authoritative.

Comment: @dbaseman The Q you linked looks unrelated to what I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know of accomplishing this is via your own class like so:

```
public partial class LocalTestDataContext
{
    [Function(Name = "IsNull", IsComposable = true)]
    [return: Parameter(DbType = "NVarChar(MAX)")]
    public string IsNull(
        [Parameter(Name = "field", DbType = "NVarChar(MAX)")] string field,
        [Parameter(Name = "output", DbType = "NVarChar(MAX)")] string output)
    {
        return ((string)(this.ExecuteMethodCall(this,
                ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())),
                field, output).ReturnValue));
    }
}
```

This is under "Take #3" from [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/zuker/archive/2010/01/30/linq-to-sql-isnull-and-ordering.aspx).

```
var ctx = new LocalTest.LocalTestDataContext(); 

var query = from c in ctx.Categories 
orderby ctx.IsNull(c.Description1, "") + ctx.IsNull(c.Description2, "") 
select c; 
query.Dump();
```

And will generate T-SQL with ISNULL().

Comment: I'd like to see something that doesn't require adding methods to the generated DataContext, but I don't think that exists.

Answer (score 1):

I always considered ISNULL and COALESCE to be equivalent, except for the number of possible parameters.

Just found that [there *are* differences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx), though, so the question is: do these differences matter to you?

Comment: My question is entirely about being able to say either "yes, you can write a LINQ to SQL query that will emit TSQL containing the ISNULL function," or "no, you can't". So, the query behavior differences really do not matter to me. It's all about capability.